# UriTypeConverter cannot convert from (null)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm running into the following NotSupportedException:

**UriTypeConverter cannot convert from (null).**

Here is the initial code where the error occurs:

```
SlideViewModel s = new SlideViewModel() { Duration = 8 };
_slideList.Add(s);
SlideView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_slideList);
SelectedSlide = s; //This is where it crashes
```

_slideList is an ObservableCollection of SlideViewModels. SelectedSlide is a SlideViewModel.

Going into the setter for the SelectedSlide property, the code is:

```
set
{
     if (_selectedSlide != value)
     {
          _selectedSlide = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSlide");
      }
 }
```

Going even further into the RaisePropertyChanged function:

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
{
     VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);
     OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

And then OnPropertyChanged:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
     if (handler != null)
     {
          handler(this, e); //Crashes here!
     }
}
```

No idea whats happening. There's no inner exception.

Answer (score 1):

You are ommiting you `XAML` binding code, but from the type of error,
`UriTypeConverter cannot convert from (null).`
Here's a possibility.
If I am understanding correctly, `SlideViewModel` is type of SlideViewModel, somewhere, you bind in `XAML` to `SlideViewModel`.

//something like this?

that some property on `SlideViewModel` is probably a string.
Uri expects a type of Uri.
If that is correct, you need to create a converter that converts from Uri to String
The use it in binding like:

```
<SomeElement Uri="{Binding SlideViewModel.SomeProperty,
                           Converter={StaticResource MyUriToStringConverter}",.../>
```

If you are alreading using a converter, make sure it handle nulls.
Again, without xaml, or your target bindings, it is really hard to see who is responding to  `SlideViewModel`'s PropertyChanged event.